# SVN 1.8.10, error when trying to merge branch with trunk

Tags: svn

We have a main trunk, and a release branch.

We frequently fix a bug or similar in the release branch, then merge it back to trunk using this:

```
cd trunkdir
svn merge https:bla.com/svn/co/proj/braches/1.1.1
```

This used to work fine, even with people commiting to both the trunk and to the branch.  I am guessing someone issued a bad command, and now it is broken. E.g. they merged the wrong thing.

We are using SVN 1.8, which forces "reintegration" when you merge.  You can't opt out of it. We are told 1.8 allows multiple - reintegrations, i.e. multiple merges from branch back to trunk without the "dance of the branch keep-alive", or conflicts.

The problem is now, out of the blue, we are getting this error:

svn: E195016: Reintegrate can only be used if revisions 1514 through 1634 were previously merged from https:bla.com/svn/co/proj/trunk to the reintegrate source, but this is not the case:
  proj/branches/1.9.11
    Missing ranges: /proj/trunk:1514,1516-1519,1555-1558,1563,1577,1586,1596-1597,1599

Any one know what this is actually saying?  Why cant we just merge the latest branch with the latest trunk, as we always have done?  We have no knowledge of revisions, and we have not needed them till now.  We don't even want to re-integrate.

NOTE: I absolutely dont want to merge from trunk to branch! I guess one solution is to manually edit each file in trunk which was changed in the branch.  Strange that it always used to work. I saw one post which suggested deleting merge info, but this sounds too dangerous.

I tried using svn:mergeinfo to find out more of whats going on.  I tried this command:

```
svn propget svn:mergeinfo
```

In both the root of the trunk and branch.  Both return nothing.  Is this correct?

Comment: Unfortunately it's telling you what you don't want to hear; normally in order to perform the branch -> Trunk you have have merged Trunk -> Branch. SVN expects that you'll cull out what you don't want during the Trunk -> Branch merges.

Comment: If this is the case, then SVN wont work for us although it has always worked till now without us having to merge trunk-branch.  It means SVN cant support a "stable" release branch with the occasional bug fix which has to go back to trunk

Comment: 1.8 changed a lot. Cherry picking is still possible, but that didn't sound like your explanation. You should check out the [SVN Advanced Merging docs](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.branchmerge.advanced.html) to see how they apply to your situation. I doubt we lost functionality, but how you do it has definitely chaged.

Comment: 1. Can you publish prepared toy-repo? I can't reproduce your scenario 2. `svn mergeinfo --show-revs` will be better way for inspecting, than pg